# How to configure AssertionConsumerServiceIndex processing in Okta?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

In my Okta App I set up `Single sign on URL` and a couple of `Requestable SSO URLs`. The idea is that I send a SAML message with index, and Okta chooses one of requestable SSO urls to send a response. Right now it doesn't take an index into account and always sends a response to `Single sign on URL`. Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't even know where to start digging.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a bug in Okta (at the time of writing).